# Echarts - Default value tooltip formatter for pie chart

Tags: pie-chart, echarts, formatter

Does somebody know what is the default `tooltip.formatter` value for pie charts ? Currently I am using version `5.4.2`, and for previous versions it was like this `{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)`, but now you can see that they added an icon near category name, and I want to catch it.

```
option = {
  //...
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  //...
}
```

[image]

I want to get something similar to this `formatter: '{b.icon} {b}: {c} ({d}%)'`. Another thing I observed is that the number in the default formatter is bold, but in mine is not.

[image: Image2]

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-simple)

Any help will be useful, thanks!

Comment: With icon you mean the color circle?

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer already

Answer (score 1):

You can get the icon via `params.marker`. The default formatter is like this.

```
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'item',
  formatter(params) {
    return `${params.seriesName}<br>${params.marker}${params.name}<span style="float: right; margin-left: 20px"><b>${params.value}</b> (${params.percent}%)</span>`;
  }
},
```

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQBKOAZjgE5OzB2wCGsA6jgEYBnCGByUANEXQCArnxHkqAMQ4BrHLAAiHMB3GTYuOhViUAxjmgjGlIgF8J6MMGBZIIAqmIZGEAOa-mKmEcAFs9LzpgRhDtKwAKEA5GDhCBAEpCL3RmMGlGOAADABIkROTUgDoBJggcAQA5FJxbAB4-RgA-ErKUgQqYxjVGW26k3oroJtaBRLgBMABPXHgAIjosYG0CH18ACzAAblgB3whoAFpDYwAmAAYQUhWOtq7SscqANw4saWaWgHo-B1YHFRuU-iAmOZLLYAKRpAEzDjQDoFA76Wx2BwGHABaAAEw8-iitUsVA-TEgpm-4WIVyoVxs6HsRGqPjqBAA2vpPFlJiF8CYAIKmcwCASwRSMYBhbFeRaQqggWq0rzJfEQaQCKgAVlusNVxHx2g4XP0XiQsC-P0FAEZbgAWAAcYlg_MFlAAyjgkqZdrAAKLQU7QUSwFlZYiW62_AgAdgAzDrXe6qBoIMxTGBKOG5Vlo99Y7AdU7bimmlQAzEIFgcxHI8grYXBc6HeWBVQAKrQKBwIX4gR1vMWps2ggJ25lt0VkwANQg-JwwFg_cH4fNsAAusPYKEQLsOEJtZkG8EQp7FrgiQ3iAID_jgAB3ABCP0YBHtO68d44D8fAHk6DoaowAADQIMsN2_e8nwAYRcKIqEYXw-A4OIpww11bgqHU0iZBtMUjQjiGIzcUFsA4gA)